# Serializing Json to c# Class throwing error

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON returning from web like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "normal_customer": {
      "0": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ALPHY"


        }
      },
      "1": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "STEVEN"          

      }

    },
    "luxury_customer": {
      "3": {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "DEV"

       }
    }
  }
}
```

I have created c# classes

```
public class StandardCustomers
{
    public List<CustomersDetails> Customers_Details { get; set; }
}

public class CustomersDetails
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public class LuxuryCustomers
    {
        public List<CustomersDetails> Customers_Details { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public StandardCustomers standard_Customers { get; set; }
        public LuxuryCustomers luxury_Customers { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I use deserialize the response from the website using below c# code

```
var result1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(response);
```

but result1.luxury_customers contains customerdetails which is null.

As suggested by @hellostone, I have modified to rootdata, then also
result1.luxury_customers contains customerdetails is null.

Any idea how to deserialize to c# class

When we pasted Json to visual studio, it generated classes as below

```
 public class Rootobject
    {
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public Standard_Customers standard_Customers { get; set; }
        public Luxury_Customers luxury_Customers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Standard_Customers
    {
        public _0 _0 { get; set; }
        public _1 _1 { get; set; }
        public _2 _2 { get; set; }
        public _4 _4 { get; set; }
        public _5 _5 { get; set; }
    }

    public class _0
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

    }
```

individual classes are generated in standard customers , can we use list for this

Comment: it seems that deserializion must be into `RootObject`.  `var result1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response)`;

Comment: @Hellowstone  I tried with rootobject , but CustomersDetails is getting null

Comment: Take your JSON and paste it into Visual Studio using `Paste Special > Paste JSON as classes` or use one of the online JSON to C# converters.

Comment: In your Json you don't return a `List<CustomerDetails>`. Members of a `List<>()` are enclosed with `[]`. So first validate your json string and make sure the right string is returned.

Comment: Json and Class structure are miles apart, try an converge them before you can get correct result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that index in `luxury_customers` starting not from zero. Try to use `Dictionary<string,CustomersDetails>` in LuxuryCustomers instead `List<CustomersDetails>`.

I've managed to deserialize Json with this classes:

```
public class CustomersDetails
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Dictionary<string, CustomersDetails> normal_customer { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,CustomersDetails> luxury_customer { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization code:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(text);
```

**P.S.** I've remove one closing bracket after "ALPHY" element, to make Json valid, I hope it was typo and you're getting valid Json.

Answer (score 0):

Your json string doesn't match with your defined classes. Your Json string should look like this if you want to preserve your class structure:

```
{
"data":{
  "standard_Customers":{
     "Customers_Details":[
        {
           "id":1,
           "name":"ALPHY"
        },
        {
           "id":2,
           "name":"STEVEN"
        }
     ]
  },
  "luxury_Customers":{
     "Customers_Details":[
        {
           "id":8,
           "name":"DEV"
        }
     ]
  }
 }
}
```

Pay attention to the *square brackets* at the "Customers_Details" attribute.

Then the:

```
var result1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
```

call, will give you the right object back and it shouldn't be `null`, when using your class structure:

```
public class StandardCustomers
{
    public List<CustomersDetails> Customers_Details { get; set; }
}

public class CustomersDetails
{
   [JsonProperty("id")]
   public int id { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("name")]
   public string name { get; set; }
}

public class LuxuryCustomers
{
   public List<CustomersDetails> Customers_Details { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public StandardCustomers standard_Customers { get; set; }
    public LuxuryCustomers luxury_Customers { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
   public Data data { get; set; }
}
```